# Sequelize WHERE sequelize.fn(...) AND something='something' ordering issue

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, postgis

I have a Sequelize findOne function that looks to select a row where the given point intersects a polygon (col 'geom') AND status = 'active'.

```
var point = sequelize.fn('ST_GeomFromText', 'POINT(' + lng + ' ' + lat +')', 4326);
var intersects = sequelize.fn('ST_Intersects', sequelize.col('geom'), point);

GeoCounty.findOne({
  attributes: ['id', 'name' ],
  where: {
    status: 'active',
    $and: intersects
  },
  plain: true
})
```

As of right now, it works just fine. It produces SQL that looks like:

```
SELECT "id", "name" FROM "geocounty" AS "geocounty" WHERE "geocounty"."status" = 'active' AND (ST_Intersects("geom", ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-98.025006 43.714735)', 4326))) LIMIT 1;
```

What I really want is:

```
SELECT "id", "name" FROM "geocounty" AS "geocounty" WHERE (ST_Intersects("geom", ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-98.025006 43.714735)', 4326))) AND "geocounty"."status" = 'active' LIMIT 1;
```

which is to say the ST_Intersects clause comes first and the AND status='active' comes after.

My questions are:
    1. Is there any sort of performance penalty for executing the query the first way which does work?
    2. Is there a way to structure a where clause like this in Sequelize?

This does not work:

```
GeoCounty.findOne({
  attributes: ['id', 'name' ],
  where: {
    intersects,
    $and: {
      status: 'active'
    }
  },
  plain: true
})
```

It produces this SQL:

```
SELECT "id", "name" FROM "geocounty" AS "geocounty" WHERE "geocounty"."intersects" = ST_Intersects("geom", ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-98.025006 43.714735)', 4326)) AND ("geocounty"."status" = 'active') LIMIT 1;
```

There is no geocounty.intersects...

Answer (score 11):

i stumbled over this post while searching for a similar problem and found a solution for me, that might help you with #2.

I wrapped the function call into an extra where. My code looks like this (works in NodeJs 10.9.0, Sequelize 4.38.0 on a MariaDB):

```
Cat.findOne({
  where: {
    color: 'red',
    $and: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('char_length', sequelize.col('cat_name')), 5)
  }
});
SELECT id, cat_name, color FROM cat_table WHERE color = 'red' AND char_length(cat_name) = 5;
```

On your example it would look like this (not tested):

```
var intersects = sequelize.fn('ST_Intersects', sequelize.col('geom'), point);
GeoCounty.findOne({
  attributes: ['id', 'name' ],
  where: {
    $and: sequelize.where(intersects, 1),
    status: 'active'
  },
  plain: true
})
```

Comment: You really saved me!

Comment: This answer helped me solve combining `sequelize.fn`, `operators` and `where` clause. Thanks