# How to use a MySQL function in Sequelize TypeScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, sequelize-typescript

I want to use the Year function on the date column as I want to compare year.

In **raw format**, we can write a query like this:

`Select * from Table where YEAR(date) = 2020`

How can we convert this query in **sequelize-typescript**?

```
class VenueSeason  {

    // ...

    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column(DataTypes.STRING(255))
    name?: string;

    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column(DataTypes.DATE)
    startDate?: Date;

    @AllowNull(false)
    @Column(DataTypes.DATE)
    endDate?: Date;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide your Sequelize `Model`?

Comment: [Does this answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43115151/sequelize-query-to-find-all-records-that-falls-in-between-date-range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use MySQL functions in Sequelize TypeScript, you can simply do this:

```
where: {
          // anyOtherColumn: //value,
          [Op.and]: where(fn('YEAR', col('startDate')), _year),
        }
```

Do import the requirements for it from Sequelize at the top:

```
import { Op, fn, col, where } from "sequelize";
```

I got the hint from this question for Sequelize (JavaScript):
*[Sequelize WHERE sequelize.fn(...) AND something='something' ordering issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43274383/sequelize-where-sequelize-fn-and-something-something-ordering-issue/52072234#52072234)*